# How to confirm Keras is loading resnet pretrained nets

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard

I am currently trying to use a pretrained ResNet50 model for my TensorFlow program. When running the train python script, I am not getting a clear indicator that it is using ResNet. Here is a snippet of the code that I have in my train script where ResNet is being used:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50

base_model = base_model_fn(ResNet50)
final_model = build_model(base_model, num_classes)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=final_model)
```

When I run the code, it says that it is creating directories for resnet and then dumps tool data into them, but it should show a download bar and install the pretrained nets, right? Where would I check to make sure it is using resnet?

Answer (score 1):

You could try it this way

```
img_shape = (224,224) # set this to the desired size

base_model=tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2( include_top=False, input_shape=img_shape, 
                               pooling='max', weights='imagenet')
x=base_model.output
output=Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

Comment: Where would I check after to make sure it is running? Is there any output that will tell me?

Comment: model.summary() will show that the model is constructed. You need to train your model with some input images and monitor the train loss and accuracy. use model,fit

Comment: Okay, I just ran it and it gave me the list of how the model is constructed. I have the input images and am able to train it with tensorboard. I wanted to verify that it was using ResNet and not a generic model

Comment: The summary printed that I have
Total params: 27,261,314
Trainable params: 27,208,194
Non-trainable params: 53,120

Comment: In this example, their resnet50 model summary had res layers. Mine does not have any http://ethen8181.github.io/machine-learning/keras/resnet_cam/resnet_cam.html